# using Nested IF to check two columns with three results

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document that I pulled out of Access. I am trying to normalize the data, but have run into an issue. I am looking at the contents of two columns and pulling out information. My formula is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(F2="False ",D2="MMR Titer"),"False ",OR(IF(AND(F2="TRUE",D2="MMR Titer"),"TRUE"," ")))
```

I get a value error.
What I need the formula to do is look at F2 and D2. If D2=`MMR Titer` and F2 = `False`, then return the false result, else, if D2=`MMr Titer` and F2 = `True`, then return the true result, else leave the field blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `OR()` in your first `else` statement.

Note that if `TRUE` is boolean, you should not include the quotes.

Comment: If I remove the OR, then everything returns a blank, except the values that are true. It does not provide me with false

Comment: @user2084933 **1.** Check that the cells having 'False' have 'false' followed by a white space. If they don't have space, they are probably stored as boolean as well. Change the formula to `F2=FALSE`). -- **2.** If your cells having 'TRUE' are stored as boolean, then you remove the quotes `"TRUE"` from the formula (to `F2=TRUE`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF(AND(F2="False ",D2="MMR Titer"),"False ",IF(AND(F2="TRUE",D2="MMR Titer"),"TRUE"," "))
```

Comment: Working, thank you so much. I did need to take the quotes from the false and the true

Comment: @user2084933 : You mean who's answer ?